# Unable to GRANT SELECT on user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, privileges, sql-grant

I initially posted a question regarding why I was given a syntax error message [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582085/mysql-places-extra-single-quote-at-end-of-line-and-raises-a-syntax-error) I then created the user `usermail` with (I admit I misused `IDENTIFIED BY` but I don't think it matters in this case:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'usermail'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'usermail';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I then retried what I was initially trying to run.

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON servermail.* TO 'usermail'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword'' at line 1
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON servermail.* TO 'usermail' IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword'' at line 1
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON servermail.* TO 'usermail'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword';
```

I am still getting the exact same error. How was my question a duplicate? Or did I not follow the directions properly?

Comment: `syntax to use near 'mysql >` That indicates that you included the prompt `mysql>` in your SQL command, an errant copy/paste.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've typed it in manually without `mysql>` and still no dice. I'll remove that errant example though.

Comment: Get rid of everything starting with `IDENTIFIED BY` in your `GRANT` statements. You only use that when creating the user.

Comment: Older versions of MySQL allowed you to use this in `GRANT` because it would create the user if necessary. Recent versions got rid of that feature.

Comment: @Barmar So I don't need `mailpassword`? Why not? Is a password not necessary here?

Comment: You set the password in the `CREATE USER` command. A user can't have multiple passwords.

Comment: If you want to change their password, use `ALTER USER`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah I see, so that initial statement is supposed to create a user, give it a password, and grant it a role in the same line, which is no longer possible.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.